# Gmail API for PHP strips out HREF

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

Gmail API for PHP strips out HREF.

Here is what is in the email that I send:

http://www.eembc.org/membership/vote.php?vote_seq=117&email=michel@degive.com'>http://www.eembc.org/membership/vote.php?vote_seq=117&email=michel@degive.com

and here is what I received when looking at source:

http://www.eembc.org/membership/vote.php?vote_seq 7&emailmichel@deg=
ive.com

it not only stripped the HREF, but also removed the = sign between the vars!

Answer (score 3):

Same thing is happening to me, but oddly not if I send email to myself.

I use a service account to automate some company internal emails.  If I send it from my own account to my own account (with the service account), it works.  If I send it to anyone else, or from anyone else, it doesn't.

From me:
http://www.mycompany.com/page">The=
 page

from or to anyone else:
http://www.mycompany.com/page">The=
 page

It's very strange.

Edit: found it on another stackoverflow post.  It's the = being used.

[Gmail removing the links tags , how to avoid this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380686/gmail-removing-the-links-tags-how-to-avoid-this)

Gotta use < a href=3D"test" > test </a>
instead of < a href="test" > test </a>

Comment: Apart from other solutions, this is working for me, but unable to figure out the reason behind 3D. Can anyone explain to me please I am a bit confusedd.